# Why an setState undefined error on a ReactJS Component handleChange method?

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate, react-dom, reactstrap

here is a simple user-profile page ReactJS + Reactstrap + Axios

I'm getting an error when using setState in handleChange method.

I tried a few ways to setState but nothing to do. It could be a deeper problem... or linked to JSON parse and stringify.

The display of the form works correctly.

Error stack :

```
 user-form.js?c7a5:69 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at handleChange (user-form.js?c7a5:69)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js?61bb:306)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js?61bb:389)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js?61bb:414)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js?61bb:3278)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js?61bb:3287)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
handleChange @ user-form.js?c7a5:69
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:292
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:306
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:389
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:414
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3278
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3287
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3257
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3304
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3514
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3558
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21871
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:795
dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:3568
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4267
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4189
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js?3069:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:11039
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:21887
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:806
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js?61bb:4168
```

user-form.js :

```
const axios = require('axios');
import React from 'react'; 
import '!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, FormText } from 'reactstrap';

class UserForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'user' : {
        'firstname' : '',
        'lastname' : '',
        'email' : '',
        'phone' : '',
        'address' : '',
        'zip' : '',
        'city' : '',
      },
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get('/api/user.php')
      .then(response => (
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,firstname: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['FIRSTNAME']))}}),       
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,lastname: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['LASTNAME']))}}),        
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,email: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['EMAIL']))}}),        
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,phone: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['MOBILE_PHONE']))}}),
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,address: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['ADDRESS']))}}), 
        this.setState({user:{...this.state.user,zip: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['POSTAL_CODE']))}}),
        this.setState({user: {...this.state.user,city: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['CITY']))}}),
        console.log({user:{...this.state.user,firstname: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data['FIRSTNAME']))}})

        ))
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <div className="user-form">
     <Form  id="user-form">
      <FormGroup  onChange={this.handleChange} id="user-data">
        <Label id="user-firstname-label">Prénom</Label>
        <Input name="firstname" id="user-firstname" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.firstname}/>
        <Label id="user-lastname-label">Nom</Label>
        <Input name="lastname" id="user-lastname" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.lastname}/>
        <Label id="user-email-label">Adresse e-mail</Label>
        <Input name="email" id="user-email" type="email" defaultValue={this.state.user.email}/>
        <Label id="user-phone-label">Numéro de téléphone</Label>
        <Input name="phone" id="user-phone" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.phone}/>
        <Label id="user-address-label">Adresse</Label>
        <Input name="adress" id="user-address" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.address}/>
        <Label id="user-zip-label">Code postal</Label>
        <Input name="zip" id="user-zip" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.zip}/>
        <Label id="user-city-label">Ville</Label>
        <Input name="city" id="user-city" type="text" defaultValue={this.state.user.city}/>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button>Sauvegarder</Button>
      </Form>
      </div> 

    );
  }
  handleChange(e) {   
    let change = ({user:{[e.target.name] : e.target.value }});
    console.log(change);
    this.setState(change);

    //OTHER TRIES

    //this.setState(JSON.stringify(change));

    // this.setState({ 
    //   user: {
    //     ...this.state.user,
    //     [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    //   },
    // });

  }           
}
export default UserForm;
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import UserProfile from './components/user-form'

ReactDOM.render(<UserProfile />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The console.log seems correct :

[image]

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript does not work like in most object oriented languages:

> A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode.
>
> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own this binding (it retains the this value of the enclosing lexical context).

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

You have to bind the `handleChange` method in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
     // ...
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}
```

or define `handleChange` as an arrow function:

```
handleChange = e => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This worked, I might need to read more about "this"